# Remove duplicates from query after LEFT JOIN

Tags: postgresql

Below, I'm using the following code to query two databases and retrieve information.

```
select p.id, p.first, p.last, p.employer, a.city, a.state, a.county 
from "Person" p 
  LEFT JOIN "Address" a ON p.id = a.person 
  LEFT JOIN "Calllist" cl on p.id = cl.person
```

This is great and works well, with the exception that it will duplicate rows occasionally. This happens in the event where a person object is associated with multiple address objects -- each duplicate will represent the identical person name with a different address. **A much simpler example is below.**

| Name | State |
| --- | --- |
| George | Virginia |
| Alex | Virginia |
| Alex | Maryland |
| Sam | West Virginia |

Instead of that being the result, where there are two lines of output for Alex, I want the results to aggregate by id and only show one output line per id.

| Name | State |
| --- | --- |
| George | Virginia |
| Alex | Virginia |
| Sam | West Virginia |

I do not care which city or state shows up in Alex's result. All I want is for his name to only show up once.

Comment: Why the join to `"Calllist"` if you are not using the table? Can there be multiple entries per person in that table, too?

Answer (score 1):

Don't multiply rows in the outer `SELECT` to begin with. That's expensive, especially when done repeatedly. See:

- [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result/12464135#12464135)

De-duplicate early:

```sql
SELECT p.id, p.first, p.last, p.employer, a.*
FROM   "Person" p
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (1)
          a.person AS id, a.city, a.state, a.county 
   FROM  "Address" a   
   ) a USING (id)
LEFT   JOIN "Calllist" cl ON p.id = cl.person;  -- seems unused?
```

That's assuming entries in `"Calllist"` are unique per person. Else, that table gets the same treatment.

About `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the results of the joins further to only include a single match which will prevent the duplication on the prior joins.

If you use tables like this

```
CREATE TABLE person (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE address (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  person INT NOT NULL,
  state VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO person VALUES
(1, 'George'),
(2, 'Alex'),
(3, 'Sam');

INSERT INTO address VALUES
(1, 1, 'Virginia'), /* George */
(2, 2, 'Virginia'), /* Alex */
(3, 2, 'Maryland'), /* Alex */
(4, 3, 'West Virginia'); /* Sam */
```

Then you can limit the addresses results by doing something like this

```
SELECT
  p.name, a.state
FROM person AS p
LEFT JOIN address AS a
  /* only include the first address */
  ON a.id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM address WHERE person = p.id)
;
```

Which will give the results

```
| George | Virginia      |
| Alex   | Virginia      |
| Sam    | West Virginia |
```

Comment: It's no problem, I just removed some redundancy from the select in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use PostgreSQL's brilliant [distinct on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46566602/what-does-distinct-on-expression-do) (you may see the answer by MatBailie).

```sql
select DISTINCT ON (p.id)
       p.id, p.first, p.last, p.employer, a.city, a.state, a.county
from "Person" p 
LEFT JOIN "Address" a ON p.id = a.person 
LEFT JOIN "Calllist" cl on p.id = cl.person;
```

Comment: This is an even better solution. Thank you.